# Is there a way to iterate over FireDAC's TFDParams using Delphi's for .. in .. do?

Tags: loops, delphi, iteration, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

With Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo), I just want to do something as simple as:

```
function ShowFinalSQL(const qry: TFDQuery): String;
var
  cSQL: String;
  oParam: TFDParam;
begin
  cSQL := qry.SQL.Text;
  for oParam in qry.Params do
    cSQL := cSQL.Replace(oParam.Name, oParam.Value);
  Result := cSQL;
end;
```

But I always get the error message:

> `[dcc32 Error] DTUtilBD.pas(3115): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TFDParam' and 'TCollectionItem'`

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`TFDQuery.Params`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.Params) is a [`TFDParams`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Param.TFDParams), which can be iterated with a [`for..in` loop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_Statements) as it has a public [`GetEnumerator()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TCollection.GetEnumerator) method.  However, that method is inherited from `TCollection` to iterate `TCollectionItem` items, so it is not specialized for `TFDParam` items (feel free to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) about that oversight).

As such, when the loop iteration tries to assign the enumerator's [`Current`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TCollectionEnumerator.Current) property to your `oParam` variable, it fails to compile because a `TCollectionItem` cannot be assigned to a `TFDParam`.  Which is exactly what the compiler error is complaining about.

Your code basically gets compiled *as-if* it had been written like this:

```pascal
function ShowFinalSQL(const qry: TFDQuery): String;
var
  cSQL: String;
  oParam: TFDParam;
  cEnum: TCollectionEnumerator;
begin
  cSQL := qry.SQL.Text;
  //for oParam in qry.Params do
  cEnum := qry.Params.GetEnumerator;
  while cEnum.MoveNext do
  begin
    oParam := cEnum.Current; // <-- ERROR HERE - cEnum.Current is TCollectionItem!
    cSQL := cSQL.Replace(oParam.Name, oParam.Value);
  end;
  Result := cSQL;
end;
```

To fix this, you need to change your `oParam` variable to be a `TCollectionItem` instead of a `TFDParam`.  You will just have to type-cast it when you want to access any `TFDParam`-specific members, eg:

```pascal
function ShowFinalSQL(const qry: TFDQuery): String;
var
  cSQL: String;
  oParam: TCollectionItem;
begin
  cSQL := qry.SQL.Text;
  for oParam in qry.Params do
    cSQL := cSQL.Replace(TFDParam(oParam).Name, TFDParam(oParam).Value);
  Result := cSQL;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
function ShowFinalSQL(const qry: TFDQuery): String;
var
  cSQL: String;
  oItem: TCollectionItem;
  oParam: TFDParam;
begin
  cSQL := qry.SQL.Text;
  for oItem in qry.Params do
  begin
    oParam := TFDParam(oItem);
    cSQL := cSQL.Replace(oParam.Name, oParam.Value);
  end;
  Result := cSQL;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: Alternatively, if you want to avoid type-casting manually, you can use [`absolute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables_(Delphi)#Absolute_Addresses):

```pascal
function ShowFinalSQL(const qry: TFDQuery): String;
var
  cSQL: String;
  oItem: TCollectionItem;
  oParam: TFDParam absolute oItem;
begin
  cSQL := qry.SQL.Text;
  for oItem in qry.Params do
  begin
    cSQL := cSQL.Replace(oParam.Name, oParam.Value);
  end;
  Result := cSQL;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @remy-lebeau! Your explanation made it simple to understand too!

Comment: Another alternartive: _var oParam: TFDParam ABSOLUTE oItem;_ Then you don't need the _oParam:=TFDParam(oItem);_ line...

Comment: @HeartWare, I didn't know the `ABSOLUTE` keyword... Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: _VAR Y : <Type> ABSOLUTE X_ defines a variable Y of type <Type> that occupies the same (starting) memory address as X. You're responsible for ensuring that it makes sense. F.ex. _VAR X : BYTE ; VAR Y : LONGINT ABSOLUTE X;_ doesn't make sense, as X only is 1 byte in size, whereas Y is 4, and you don't know what the three bytes after X is. If you want to overlay two variables, make sure that you define the smaller one ABSOLUTE the larger one. If both variables are CLASSes or POINTERs they always occupy the same amount of bytes, so they can be overlaid on top of each other without restriction.

Comment: One use I often do is in Event handlers. Sender is usually a simple TObject, but if I _know_ that I always call it from an event of a - say - TButton, I usually declare _VAR BTN : TButton ABSOLUTE Sender;_ so I can access the Sender under its proper type (I then usually do an _ASSERT(Sender IS TButton);_ at the entry of the event handler, to make sure...) @FábioAmorim

Comment: How was possible for me to pass about 3 years developing in Delphi without knowing about this?? 
Thank you very **very** much @HeartWare!

Comment: @HeartWare, you should add your comment as an answer too. So I could mark it as correct as well. After all, it was I used in my code.

Comment: @HeartWare the `is` operator performs an RTTI type check at runtime. So, if you are going to invoke that overhead anyway, you may as well just skip using `absolute` and use the `as` operator instead, which performs the same check and converts at the same time: `var Btn: TButton; Btn := Sender as TButton;` That will raise an exception if the conversion fails.

Comment: @FábioAmorim only 1 answer can be marked as accepted at a time. I have added an `absolute` example to my answer

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, the IS operator performs RTTI check - but as I use it in ASSERT statement, it is NULL'ed out in RELEASE builds (or if you turn off assertions). That's why I do it this way and does not use AS.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like `TFDParams.Items[]` also uses casting to provide a TFDParam item. From unit `FireDAC.Stan.Param` > `TFDParams.GetItem()`: `Result := TFDParam(inherited Items[Index]);` (Delphi 10.4.2)